# Scrolling a Div function animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

https://katieandemil.academy/what-is-a-database

After reaching to footer it is creating more space. How can I resolve it. I want to stop it while it will reach to footer.

My JS function:

```
$(function() {

    var $sidebar   = $("#sidebar"), 
        $window    = $(window),
        offset     = $sidebar.offset(),
        topPadding = 75;
      var _docHeight = (document.height !== undefined) ? document.height : document.body.offsetHeight;



      var footer_top = $("#footer").offset().top;
      var div_top = $('#sticky-anchor').offset().top;
      var div_height = $("#sidebar").height();

      var desiredHeight = _docHeight - footer_top;

    $window.scroll(function()
    {
        if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top)
        {
            $sidebar.stop().animate({
                marginTop: $window.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
            });
        }

        else if($window.scrollTop > desiredHeight)
        {
            $sidebar.stop().animate({
                marginTop: $window.scrollTop()-100
            });
        }
        else {
            $sidebar.stop().animate({
                marginTop: 0
            });
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class `.well` has the property `margin-bottom: 50px` which is creating 50 pixels of space below the final 2 elements, extending the page length. Removing `margin-bottom` from your class will correct it.

```
.well {
   padding: 30px;
}
```

Comment: No. It's not giving any solution.

Comment: @NafeeurRahman the following image demonstrates removing the margin-bottom override removes the extra space at the bottom of the page. https://i.imgur.com/GDML6VH.png

Comment: inspect on <nav> tab, it is creating a margin-top. We should prevent its automatic increasing before footer.

Comment: @NafeeurRahman Please explain what you are trying to achieve here

Comment: Scrolling will stop before footer. After coming to footer if I press down press it is creating space. I want that, when it will close to footer it will stop scrolling.